# How to get dynamic string values generated in a java class in a serlvet...?

Tags: java, servlets, dynamic-values

I'm working on a simple web application. This application has a functionality 'ping' which we usually do from command prompt.
 So in my jsp page i'll give an address like 'www.google.com' and click submit to send the address to my servlet called 'PingServlet'. My servlet receives the address and sends to a java class which will processes the pinging of that address.

```
    ip="www.google.com"; //Got from servlet
    String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;
    //ArrayList<String> pingRsult = new ArrayList<String>();
    //pingRsult.add("Pinging Data");
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                .getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);//i want to send this string to servlet
        }
        in.close();

    }// try
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

while processing the address, in while loop it'll produce the some string values, in which i want to send each string value to servlet when it is generated. I've searched google a lot. But i didn't found any idea....

Please Help me out...!

Answer (score 0):

You can put an ArrayList pingResults; as a session variable...

Then you just need to read from the jsp page.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            ArrayList<String> pingResult=new ArrayList<>();
            HttpSession s = request.getSession();

            //Add your values
            s.setAttribute("Values", values);
            //Redirect to jsp where you show the strings
            response.sendRedirect("exemple.jsp");
}
```

Then in your jsp you just need to call the session variable `Values`

If you want a real time printing you can use the code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD><TITLE>Ping Result</TITLE></HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");


    ip="www.google.com"; //Got from servlet
    String pingCmd = "ping " + ip;
    ArrayList<String> pingRsult = new ArrayList<String>();
    pingRsult.add("Pinging Data");
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                .getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            out.println("<p>"+inputLine+"</p>");
        }
        in.close();                        
            out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    }// try
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

This way each line the servlet reads, she prints it on the servlet page.

Comment: Thanks Manuel Pires.. I think you didn't understand my question properly. In the code that i've given, while loop produces strings each time right..? i need to send that generated string each time to servlet as soon as it is generated.

Comment: And you want to come again to this servlet and continue the while?

Comment: I believe that the only way to do that is using threads, and I think that's forbidden in J2EE Standart... Do you want to treat the values or just print them in that servlet?

Comment: I want to print those values in my jsp page

Comment: I believe it's only possible with the first example I have above... You create a session/request attribute with the full result, and then you send it to your jsp page...

Answer (score 0):

Use Request scope or session scope to store the value and use the same in the servlet.